# Publishing app to Cloud Foundry errors: exceeded organization's memory limit. How to fix?

Tags: command-line-interface, cloud-foundry

I am trying to host a Mendix app on Mindsphere through Cloud Foundry, but my attempts at using the `cf push` operation fails.
The fail states that my organization's memory limit has been exceeded - this error occurs regardless of the amount of memory being specified through the optional -m argument passed to cf push.

[image: Log from using cf push to publish Mendix app to Cloud Foundry]

Following is information about the organization, of which its quota has allocated 2GB memory, and the other spaces besides my space `iot_demo_AMD` barely takes up a few hundreds of MB, which is nowhere close to the 2GB limit.

[image: Log from getting organization information, current space & organization quote]

And here is the health and status of the app in question:
[image: Health and status of app]

Let me know if there's a better suited place to ask this, or if more information is necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: There's two ways to fix this: 1.) Stop/Delete apps so that it frees up memory in your quota. If you're not sure which apps are consuming the memory, see @Pavel's answer below. 2.) Talk to your platform operator and ask them to give you a larger quota.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging the screenshot you've provided, you have 3 spaces.
Probably, some of them use quota which didn't count on.
You can also see the summary of your org if you have doubts.

```
cf org <name of your org> --guid
```

will output your organization id.

```
cf curl /v2/organizations/<organization id>/summary
```

will return json object with spaces and total memory they are consuming (look at mem_dev_total property).

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

### It is Typo Error

If you are working on cloud with Git CI-CD, Please Check your spelling in your **push-cf.yml** file under your **project dir**.

```
name: Build and deploy to IBM Cloud Foundry

on: workflow_dispatch

# Environment variables available to all jobs and steps in this workflow

    env:
      IBM_CLOUD_REGION: us-south
      IBM_CLOUD_GROUP: *Default*
      IBM_CLOUD_SPACE: dev
      IBM_CLOUD_ORG: XXXXXXX@gmail.com
      MANIFEST_NAME: manifest.yml
      IBM_CLOUD_API: ${{secrets.IBM_CLOUD_API_KEY}}
```

It works for me only by changing the first letter of *default* to *Default*
I get this info from my *GitHub actions workflow logs*, use yours please.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connected to right org and API endpoint.

If you are connected correctly, increase the memory more.  I found this in the docs , could you try pushing the app again but set the disk to 3 GB or higher :

```
ibmcloud cf push appname -p app_path -k disk_quota
```

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-ts-cf-apps#ts_disk_quota